# How to share file or folder on over internet by using public IP?

Tags: windows

my boss just asking me to create 1 share folder that be able to access from every where over internet connection(same ask local share folder and we will not use FTP Server).

Comment: Do you have a static IP? Do you have a server in the office? Do you need permissions (e.g. passwords)? Do you have any sort of http daemon running on the server? This is too broad of a question.

Comment: see: http://superuser.com/questions/284774/access-windows-shares-on-remote-computer

Answer (score -1):

You can't without FTP/WEB server.

Comment: it could be possible: http://superuser.com/questions/284774/access-windows-shares-on-remote-computer

Comment: So, no more way to do right, do we have any port or other way to do it?